# How can I have 2 language auto signature?

Tags: outlook, signature

i have 2 languages installed in outlook, English (left to right) and Arabic (Right to left) and created 2 different signatures. I can assign each signature manually to each language but i want to know is it possible that signature assign automatically when i change the language or the direction. and how ?

Answer (score 0):

No, Outlook does not do that out of the box.